# When I use .copy() in python, why does it still make references of one dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, I want to make a 2D array with dictionaries. I do have knowledge of references, so I explicitly used `.copy`. When I print the array out, however, the dictionaries that I do not want to be changed also changes.
My code is below.

```py
dicts = []
for j in range(3):
    dicts.append([{0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0}.copy()].copy() * 3)

dicts[0][0][0] = 5
dicts[1][1][0] = 10
print(dicts)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[[{0: 5, 1: 0}, {0: 5, 1: 0}], [{0: 0, 1: 10}, {0: 0, 1: 10}]]
```

Does anyone know why this happens, and anyway to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: See the duplicate, and note that using `copy` this way doesn't change anything, as you still get 3 times the same dict object.

Comment: None of your calls to `copy` are useful. You are just working with references to *copies* of the objects created by the displays, rather than the originals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this kind of thing cleanly is with list comprehensions:

```
dicts = [[{0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0} for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
dicts[0][0][0] = 5
dicts[1][1][0] = 10
print(dicts)
```

Output:

```
[[{0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}], [{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}, {0: 10, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}], [{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}]]
```

Comment: Weird. This question was closed quite a while before your answer was posted. (I posted my comment on the question after it was closed while typing up my own answer.)

Comment: I noticed that after I answered and felt slightly guilty.  Not sure why it worked.

Comment: I should say, nothing wrong with your answer at all, just surprised it slipped through :)